# CSSOMParser errors during parsing

Tags: java, xml, css-parsing

I am getting the following errors while parsing css file [all.css](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css)

```
null [1:1763] Error in style rule. Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ",", ";", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:1763] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:4352] Error in style rule. Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ",", ";", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:4352] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:4435] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:4435] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:10349] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:10349] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:12131] Error in style rule. Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ",", ";", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:12131] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:17335] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:17335] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:20115] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:20115] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:20499] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:20499] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:22593] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:22593] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:23137] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, ",", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:27252] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:27252] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:28495] Error in style rule. Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ",", ";", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:28495] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:32022] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:32022] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:33926] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:33926] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:34660] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:34660] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:36410] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:36410] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:36624] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:36624] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:37378] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:37378] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:39110] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:39110] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:40536] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:40536] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:41061] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:41061] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:41487] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:41487] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:45987] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, ",", "/", "+", "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMEN>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, "rgb(", <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>, <UNICODERANGE>.
null [1:45992] Error in style rule. Invalid token "position". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
null [1:45992] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:46761] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:46761] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:50353] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:50353] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
null [1:51070] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
null [1:51070] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
```

It looks related to broken css tags. Can somebody please clarify on this?
I am using the css rules in the file to figure out certain elements on the html page (which linked to the css). Will these errors actually effect the parsing of the css rules and hence the profiling of the html elements on the web page? (I am sure it does but hope it does not)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you're using non-standard CSS rules like "!ie7", or vendor specific properties like "-moz-border-radius"?

Comment: So this being a problem, I should not worry about the rules being ignored as they might be very vendor specific?? Am I right?

Comment: I would think it's not likely to cause you a problem.

Answer (score -2):

You must escape the characters when you are parsing. Apache has the `StringEscapeUtils` class which can help you.
I think you must use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML(readedText);` due to html and css syntax are more similar.

Regards!

Comment: The OP is parsing a stand-alone CSS file, so no escaping of HTML entities is required.